# argsort in Thrust

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, cuda, thrust

Is it legal to use `thrust::sort_by_key` like in following code?

```cpp
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/advance.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
    
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
    
int main()
{
    int init[] = {2, 0, 1, 3, 4};
    const thrust::device_vector< int > v{std::cbegin(init), std::cend(init)};
        
    thrust::device_vector< std::intptr_t > index{v.size()};
    thrust::sequence(index.begin(), index.end());
        
    auto key = 
        thrust::make_permutation_iterator(
            thrust::make_transform_iterator(
                v.cbegin(), 
                thrust::identity< thrust::tuple< int > >{}),
            index.cbegin());
    thrust::sort_by_key(
        key,
        thrust::next(key, index.size()),
        index.begin());
        
    thrust::copy(
        index.cbegin(), index.cend(),
        std::ostream_iterator< std::intptr_t >(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Here `index` array points to `v` array of values. I want to have a "sorted view" of `v.index` after above sorting is the view, that is `[v[i] for i in index]` (pythonic pseudocode) is sorted.

The trick with `identity` transformation is crucial here: it transform values pointed to by `index` in `v` to one-element-tuple. `thrust::tuple` is a class and have `operator =`, which is not cv-ref-qualified for lvalues only and thus can be used on rvalues just returned as a result of dereferencing of the `transform_iterator`. `thrust::tuple< int >(1) = 2;` is a legal statement and effectively is a no-op, because left hand side value dropped right after the assignment. As a result key swaps in `sort_by_key` are all no-ops and real sorting occurs in "values" part of key-value sorting. Also not, that `v` is immutable here (result `v.cbegin()` is const iterator).

As I know, developers of Thrust generally assume, that all callables are [idempotent](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/issues/836#issuecomment-336362140). I believe the assumption is not violated here, because only the argument of the callable (`thrust::identity`) changed, not a state of the callable. But on the other hand any superposition of Thrust fancy iterators can be considered as a composition of a functions (say, `permutation_iterator` is a simple mapping).

In `sort_by_key` `index` is read and written. It can be prohibited by implicit rules of implementation. Is it correct code?

Comment: What is the question? This appears to compile and run, but the output is the same as the input (`2, 1, 0, 3, 4`).

Comment: @harrism The question is "is it correct?" Say, it is not legal/correct for `union { int i; float f; } u; u.i = 1;` to inspect (read) `u.f;` in C++. It generally works, but it is not allowed by the Standard.

Comment: In `sort_by_key` `index` is read and written. It can be prohibited by implicit rules of implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I cannot answer the question if your implementation is relying on undefined behavior or on algorithmic implementation-details not causing race conditions on `index`, there is a way of implementing *argsort* in Thrust using `thrust::sort` with a custom comparator instead of `thrust::sort_by_key` that is much more readable and therefore easier to argue about:

```cpp
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/advance.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>

#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int init[] = {2, 0, 1, 3, 4};
    const thrust::device_vector< int > v{std::cbegin(init), std::cend(init)};

    // optimization to avoid unnecessary initialization of index to zero
    auto const seq_iter =
        thrust::make_counting_iterator(
            static_cast< std::intptr_t >(0));

    thrust::device_vector< std::intptr_t > index{seq_iter,
                                                 thrust::next(seq_iter, v.size())};
    
    auto const v_ptr = v.data();

    thrust::sort(
        index.begin(), index.end(),
        [v_ptr] __host__ __device__ (std::intptr_t left_idx, std::intptr_t right_idx)
        {
            return v_ptr[left_idx] < v_ptr[right_idx];
        });

    thrust::copy(
        index.cbegin(), index.cend(),
        std::ostream_iterator< std::intptr_t >(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Due to the device lambda, nvcc needs the `-extended-lambda` flag to compile this snippet. One can implement the comparator for `sort` with a named functor instead of a lambda to avoid the need for this flag. I used a `__host__ __device__` lambda as **pure** `__device__` lambdas are [generally problematic](https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/issues/779#issuecomment-702336832).